# Why can't I declare a string in my program: "string is undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I can't declare a string in my program:

```
string MessageBoxText = CharNameTextBox->Text;
```

it just doesn't work. It says `string is undeclared identifier`. What am I missing in the namespace or include or something like that?

Comment: Who said `CharNameTextBox->Text` is convertible to std::string?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure you've included this header:

```
#include <string>
```

And then use `std::string` instead of `string`. It is because `string` is defined in `std` namespace.

And don't write this at namespace scope:

```
using namespace std; //bad practice if you write this at namespace scope
```

However, writing it at function scope is not that bad. But the best is one which I suggested before:

**Use `std::string`** as:

```
std::string MessageBoxText = CharNameTextBox->Text;
```

Comment: Where do i put it in my program, i have tried that perviously, but i just get a hundred lines of errors wherever i put it

Comment: It needs to be outside any other code, at the top of your file. Post some code perhaps?

Comment: are you sure you are compiling C++ and not C?

Comment: Please don't recommend `using namespace std;` to beginners.

Comment: i don't think it'd be called visual c++ if it was just c :/

Answer (score 3):

To use the standard `string` class in C++ you need to `#include <string>`. Once you've added the `#include` directive `string` will be defined in the `std` namespace and you can refer to it as `std::string`.

E.g.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string hw( "Hello, world!\n" );
    std::cout << hw;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just edited Scott's answer to make that better, and  then refreshed the page, it shows up yours as well. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any way compiling using C++/CLI, the Microsoft extension for .NET, and not standard ISO C++?

In that case you should do the following:

```
System::String^ MessageBoxText = CharNameTextBox->Text;
```

Also see the following articles:

- [How to: Convert Between Various String Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx)
- [How to: Convert System::String to Standard String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623.aspx)
- [How to: Convert Standard String to System::String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx)